# 'stripeToken' error when attempting to submit payment form

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I'm following an outdate django e-commerce course using django and stripe. The course is about 4 years old so a lot has changed with django and stripe, which has allowed me to do a ton of research on both. I'm at the end of the tutorial and have run into an issue while creating the checkout page and more importantly using stripe to 'Create Charge'. I am receiving the following error message:

> django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError
>   django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'stripeToken'

I read in the documentation for [Creating Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/charges#creating-charges) which states

> token = request.POST['stripeToken'] # Using Flask

is for Flask (I think), however when i remove ['stripeToken'], I receive this error message:

> stripe.error.InvalidRequestError stripe.error.InvalidRequestError:
>   Request req_kikB88HKbEkq9W: Could not find payment information

I need a way to pass Stripe the payment information when the form is submitted. Also, I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885695/multivaluedictkeyerror-exception-value-stripetoken?rq=1) but the publisher was receiving error message do to multiple forms

view.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
import stripe

stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
# Create your views here.

@login_required
def checkout(request):
    publish_key = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
    if request.method == 'POST':
        token = request.POST['stripeToken']
        stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=999,
            currency='usd',
            description='Example charge',
            source=token,
            statement_descriptor='Custom descriptor',
        )
    context = {'publish_key': publish_key}
    template = 'checkout.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

checkout.html

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="col-sm-6 offset-md-3">
          <h4 class="mb-3">Billing address</h4>
          <form id="payment-form" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="firstName">First name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" required style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%;" required/>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Valid first name is required.
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" required />
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Valid last name is required.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="email">Email <span class="text-muted"></span></label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="you@example.com" required />
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please enter a valid email address for shipping updates.
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="address">Address</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="1234 Main St" required />
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please enter your shipping address.
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="address2">Address 2 <span class="text-muted"></span></label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address2" placeholder="Apartment or suite" />
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                <label for="city">City</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" required />
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Zip code required.
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label for="state">State</label>
                <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="state" required>
                  <option value="">Choose...</option>
                  <option>California</option>
                </select>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Please provide a valid state.
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                <label for="zip">Zip</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" required />
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Zip code required.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="mb-4">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="same-address">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="same-address">Shipping address is the same as my billing address</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="save-info">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="save-info">Save this information for next time</label>
            </div>
            <hr class="mb-4">

            <h4 class="mb-3">Payment</h4>

                <div class="d-block my-3">
                <label for="card-element">Credit or debit card</label>
                    <div id="card-element" class="form-control" style='height: 2.4em; padding-top: .7em;'>
                    <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                     </div>
                     <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
                    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                </div>
            <hr class="mb-4">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Continue to checkout</button>
          </form>
        </div>

{% endblock %}
```

app.js

```
// Create a Stripe client.
const stripe = Stripe('{{ publish_key }}');

// Create an instance of Elements.
const elements = stripe.elements();

// Create an instance of the card Element.
const card = elements.create('card', {});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#card-element');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
card.addEventListener('change', ({error}) => {
  const displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (error) {
    displayError.textContent = error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

// Create a token or display an error when the form is submitted.
const form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const {token, error} = await stripe.createToken(card);

  if (error) {
    // Inform the customer that there was an error.
    const errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    errorElement.textContent = error.message;
  } else {
    // Send the token to your server.
    stripeTokenHandler(token);
  }
});

// Submit the form with the token ID.
const stripeTokenHandler = (token) => {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  const form = document.getElementById('payment-form'),
        hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

  // Submit the form
  form.submit();
}
```

Comment: "stripToken" is not being passed in the form data, can you inspect the request in your browser's dev tools to confirm that? Is your "submit" event handler actually being run before the form is submitted?

Comment: i'm now getting a invalid api_key error message ' https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens 401'

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: In checkout.html i forgot to add the ID "payment-form" also changed const stripe = Stripe('{{ publish_key }}'); by removing publish_key and adding the actual publishable key... im going to figure out how to include reference to the publishable key. thank you for your help

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem which I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60981910/django-python-stripe-stripetoken-doesnt-seem-to-load-work-properly

Any answer on this?

Comment: The tutorial I was following was outdated and I was unable to gather the relevant info needed to correct the error. I came across an open source e-commerce solution called saleor. I