# Django/Python Stripe stripeToken doesn't seem to load/work properly

Tags: python, django, django-views, stripe-payments

I am trying to charge a subscription on Stripe API in test-mode and my charge keeps getting declined. Everything seems to be working fine, except I cannot retrieve the "stripeToken" via POST. I tested this by printing the various variables I need and they all work fine... but when it comes to printing stripeToken, I get this error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /memberships/payment/
'stripeToken'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/memberships/payment/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    
'stripeToken'
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 80
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.2
Python Path:    
['/Users/fred/Documents/yonder/videoservice',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python38.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/fred/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 1 Apr 2020 16:20:53 -0700
```

Here is my view code:

```
def PaymentView(request):
    user_membership = get_user_membership(request)
    try:
        selected_membership = get_selected_membership(request)
    except:
        return redirect(reverse("memberships:select"))
    publishKey = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
    if request.method == "POST":
        token = request.POST['stripeToken']
        try:
            token = request.POST['stripeToken']

            customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(user_membership.stripe_customer_id)
            customer.source = token # 4242424242424242
            customer.save()

            subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
                customer=user_membership.stripe_customer_id,
                items=[
                    { "plan": selected_membership.stripe_plan_id },
                ]
            )

            return redirect(reverse('memberships:update-transactions',
                                    kwargs={
                                        'subscription_id': subscription.id
                                    }))

        except:
            messages.info(request, "An error has occurred, investigate it in the console")

    context = {
        'publishKey': publishKey,
        'selected_membership': selected_membership
    }

    return render(request, "memberships/membership_payment.html", context)
```

And here is my HTML code

```
{% extends 'courses/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/checkout.css' %}">


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Payment</h1>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <p>Selected Membership: {{ selected_membership }}</p>
            <p>Price: ${{ selected_membership.price }}<small>/mo.</small></p>



            <button onclick="toggleDisplay();" class="btn btn-warning" style="width: 100%;">Checkout with a credit card</button>


            <div id="collapseStripe" class="wrapper">
              <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>


              <form action="." method="post" id="payment-form">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-row">
                  <label for="card-element">
                    Credit or debit card
                  </label>
                  <div id="card-element" class="StripeElement StripeElement--empty"><div class="__PrivateStripeElement" style="margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; border: none !important; display: block !important; background: transparent !important; position: relative !important; opacity: 1 !important;"><iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" name="__privateStripeFrame3" allowpaymentrequest="true" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/elements-inner-card-8a434729e4eb82355db4882974049278.html#style[base][color]=%2332325d&amp;style[base][lineHeight]=18px&amp;style[base][fontFamily]=%22Helvetica+Neue%22%2C+Helvetica%2C+sans-serif&amp;style[base][fontSmoothing]=antialiased&amp;style[base][fontSize]=16px&amp;style[base][::placeholder][color]=%23aab7c4&amp;style[invalid][color]=%23fa755a&amp;style[invalid][iconColor]=%23fa755a&amp;componentName=card&amp;wait=false&amp;rtl=false&amp;features[noop]=false&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com&amp;referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com%2Fdocs%2Fstripe-js%2Felements%2Fquickstart&amp;controllerId=__privateStripeController0" title="Secure payment input frame" style="border: none !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; width: 1px !important; min-width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden !important; display: block !important; height: 18px;"></iframe><input class="__PrivateStripeElement-input" aria-hidden="true" style="border: none !important; display: block !important; position: absolute !important; height: 1px !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; width: 100% !important; opacity: 0 !important; background: transparent !important; pointer-events: none !important; font-size: 16px !important;"><input class="__PrivateStripeElement-safariInput" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="border: none !important; display: block !important; position: absolute !important; height: 1px !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; width: 100% !important; opacity: 0 !important; background: transparent !important; pointer-events: none !important; font-size: 16px !important;"></div></div>

                  <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
                  <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                </div>

                <button>Submit Payment</button>
              </form>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div id="stripe-token-handler" class="is-hidden">Success! Got token: <span class="token"></span></div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- script for the stripe form -->
            <script src="{% static 'js/checkout.js' %}"></script>

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

            <!-- script for toggling display of the form -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function toggleDisplay() {
                  var x = document.getElementById("collapseStripe");
                  if (x.style.display === "none") {
                      x.style.display = "block";
                  } else {
                      x.style.display = "none";
                  }
                };
            </script>


            {% endblock content %}
```

And here is checkout.js

```
// Create a Stripe client.

var stripe = Stripe('123456'); //key goes here

  // Create an instance of Elements.
  var elements = stripe.elements();

  // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
  // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
  var style = {
    base: {
      color: '#32325d',
      lineHeight: '18px',
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      fontSize: '16px',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4'
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: '#fa755a',
      iconColor: '#fa755a'
    }
  };

  // Create an instance of the card Element.
  var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
  card.mount('#card-element');

  // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
  card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  // Handle form submission.
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error.
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server.
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });

  });

  var successElement = document.getElementById('stripe-token-handler');
  document.querySelector('.wrapper').addEventListener('click', function() {
    successElement.className = 'is-hidden';
  });

  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    successElement.className = '';
    successElement.querySelector('.token').textContent = token.id;
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
  }
```

My Public/Secret API Keys are in my settings file and I've double-checked them; they're both correct.

What am I doing wrong here? This is my first Django/Python project. Appreciate some insight. Thanks.

Comment: Issue is in `checkout.js`. Can you show the code for that as well.

Comment: If this is a greenfield project, I'd recommend using the new Stripe hosted Checkout: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout    which uses Stripe.js v3 and stripe.redirectToCheckout. The card element you've added also looks wrong, that looks like it was manually rendered rather than generated by mounting it with Stripe.js?

Comment: Added checkout.js in edit.